# Changing the value of a css variable from JS causes strange behavior

Tags: javascript, css, electron

```
:root{
    --name: "＊";
}

.test::before{
    font-size: 13px;
    Content: var(--name);
}
```

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--name", "test");
```

I want to manipulate the above css variables as in this JS, but when I run this JS, the "*" just disappears and "test" is not reflected. Do you know the cause?

(Translated by DeepL)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do like below. Note the extra quote I added:

```js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--name", "'test'");
```

```css
:root{
    --name: "＊";
}

.test::before{
    font-size: 13px;
    Content: var(--name);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!
Also, by the way, how do I specify a variable?

document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--name", a);

Comment: @さかな like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ds5mqy7b/?